# ERROR: "react-scripts:start" exited with 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does anybody know how to fix this error? I can't start yarn without this showing up.

Thank you

my scripts code in my package.json looks like this

```
"scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css --watch",
    "react-scripts:start": "timeout <5> && react-scripts start",
    "react-scripts:dist": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "run-p watch:css react-scripts:start",
    "build": "run-s build:css react-scripts:dist",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more ? How did you create the react project, which commands you used ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika my scripts code in my package.json looks like this...`"scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css --watch",
    "react-scripts:start": "timeout <5> && react-scripts start",
    "react-scripts:dist": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "run-p watch:css react-scripts:start",
    "build": "run-s build:css react-scripts:dist",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },`

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I used "cd my app" then "yarn start" before I received this error

Comment: How did you create react project? Is it `npx create-react-app my-app` ?

Comment: I used `npm i -g create-react-app`